# KnockoutJS Validate - getting element's css class added

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm having trouble getting [knockout validate](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) to add an error css class to my input.

I have it configured like this:

```
var knockoutValidationSettings = {
    insertMessages: true,
    decorateElement: true,
    errorMessageClass: 'error',
    errorElementClass: 'error',
    errorClass: 'error',
    errorsAsTitle: true,
    parseInputAttributes: false,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    decorateElementOnModified: true
};

data.vm = new vmFunc();

ko.applyBindingsWithValidation(data.vm, $('#claimsSettingsSubmodule')[0], knockoutValidationSettings);
```

The span is getting added with the appropriate css class, but the input is remaining unchanged.

The input's html looks like this

```
<input type="text" id="claims-settings-referrer-name" data-bind="value: referrerName" />
```

It seems to work if I do this

```
<input type="text" id="claims-settings-referrer-name" data-bind="value: referrerName, validationElement: referrerName" />
```

but that's less than optimal to say the least.

Comment: Can you post your view model? Where are applying the actual validation elements?

Comment: A fiddle is always helpful as well

Comment: Gah - works in the fiddle.  This is the most frustrating plugin I've ever used.

Comment: You can try to set the `decorateInputElement: true` in your `knockoutValidationSettings`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to automatically decorate your the input elements with the `errorElementClass` you need to set the `decorateInputElement` property to `true` in your `knockoutValidationSettings`

```
var knockoutValidationSettings = {
    insertMessages: true,
    decorateElement: true,
    errorMessageClass: 'error',
    errorElementClass: 'error',
    errorClass: 'error',
    errorsAsTitle: true,
    parseInputAttributes: false,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    decorateElementOnModified: true,
    decorateInputElement: true
};
```

The `decorateElementOnModified` only works together with the `validationElement` binding as you've already noted.